# Authenticating using .boto google cloud storage api

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, boto

Having issues with the google cloud storage api. followed the setup from here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Here is my code, it should just print the files in the bucket. This structure worked with an earlier version of the oauth2plugin but cannot get it to work with the new gcs modules.

```
from gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin import oauth2_plugin
from os import path
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

uri = boto.storage_uri(mybucket,'gs')
for obj in uri.get_bucket():
    print obj.name
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Tim.Samain\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\SVN\WW_7861_DL.py", line 37, in <module>
    for obj in uri.get_bucket():   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\storage_uri.py", line 181, in get_bucket
    conn = self.connect()   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\storage_uri.py", line 140, in connect
    **connection_args)   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\gs\connection.py", line 47, in
__init__
    suppress_consec_slashes=suppress_consec_slashes)   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\connection.py", line 190, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 572, in
__init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\auth.py", line 926, in get_auth_handler
    ready_handlers.append(handler(host, config, provider))   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin\gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin\oauth2_plugin.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.oauth2_client = oauth2_helper.OAuth2ClientFromBotoConfig(config)   File "C:\gsutil\gsutil\third_party\gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin\gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin\oauth2_helper.py", line 121, in OAuth2ClientFromBotoConfig
    'client_id for your application obtained from ' Exception: client_id for your application obtained from https://console.developers.google.com must be set in a boto config or with OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID environment variable or with gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin.SetFallbackClientIdAndSecret function.
```

I have my `.boto` file configured as per the setup docs. Just not sure why I am getting this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up specifying the client_id and client_secret explicitly in the .boto file.

This is discussed here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary

But isn't mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#config
which talks about configuring the .boto file

The code as shared above then functions as expected and prints all the files in the bucket.